# Conditions paginate cakephp

Tags: cakephp, conditional-statements, pagination

I tried it

```
public function index($id = null)
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Photos'],
    ];
   // $tareas = $this->paginate($this->Tareas);

    $this->loadModel('Categorias');

    if(isset($id)){
        $tareas2 = $this->Tareas->find()->where(['categoria_id'=>$id])->all();
        $tareas = $this->paginate($tareas2);
    }
    else
    {
        $tareas = $this->paginate($this->Tareas);
    }

        $categorias = $this->Categorias->find()->all();



    $this->set(compact('tareas','categorias'));
}
```

Is working when dont pass id but when i passed id i get this error

Call to undefined method Cake\ORM\ResultSet::getAlias()

Answer (score 2):

The paginator accepts only table names, table instances (`\Cake\Datasource\RepositoryInterface`), and query instances (`\Cake\Datasource\QueryInterface`).

Do not call `all()` on your query object, that will execute the query and return a result set, ie an instance of `\Cake\ORM\ResultSet`, instead pass the query object.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Pagination > Using Controller::paginate()](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-controller-paginate)**

Answer (score 1):

OK i resolved it with this

```
public function index($id = null)
{
    if(isset($id)){
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Photos'],
            'conditions' => ['categoria_id'=>$id]
        ];
    }
    else{
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Photos'],
        ];
    }
    $tareas = $this->paginate($this->Tareas);

    $this->loadModel('Categorias');

    $categorias = $this->Categorias->find()->all();


    $this->set(compact('tareas','categorias'));
}
```